# Where does Chrome stores offline books downloaded using Amazon-Cloud Extension on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, kindle

I've downloaded from Amazon a few books using the Chrome Cloud Reader extension.

The only possible way to view those books is from inside the Chrome Reader extension , and let's be frank , it's pretty much a very annoying extension .

I want to view those books (I guess **.mobi** files) in my own viewer (**Calibre**) , but I can't find the books that chrome downloaded  (I'm working offline so I downloaded the books , but they're invisible) .

Where is Chrome storing those offline books?

Comment: This answer provides some great insight too: https://askubuntu.com/a/1012193/327339

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So this doesn't directly answer your question, but if you're trying to find the .mobi files for use with Calibre, I would just download the [Kindle for PC application](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html/ref=kcp_pc_mkt_lnd?docId=1000426311) and find the downloaded files for importing into Calibre.

They're stored in...

- **Windows**: `Libraries/Documents/My Kindle Content`
- **macOS**: `~/Library/Containers/com.amazon.Kindle/Data/Library/Application Support/Kindle/My Kindle Content`

Comment: Great answer , this program stores the downloaded files in `Libraries/Documents/My Kindle Content` .

Comment: yet some ebooks - like comics for instance - are restricted to tablet and chrome cloud reader extension. so this doesn't really like a valid solution for me.

Comment: Currently Amazon provides platform-based links only. Thus, it's not possible to download the K4PC-App on a Linux machine.

Answer (score 15):

I think I've found where it stores them, but you won't like it.

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\databases\https_read.amazon.com_0
```

Contains a couple of files that don't have file extensions. They are SQLite 3 files. If you keep track of the file size and last edited time when you download a book, it gets bigger and is modified at the same time. Having potentially found the book, I still didn't get anywhere. Looking at the database in Sqlite Browser, it seems that the books are broken apart into thousands of fragments.

Comment: Yes, they seem to have moved the files to the location that Boon shows above.  I can't do anything with it either, although somebody on GitHub has a script they claim will retrieve the book text as html.  I haven't tried it, I'm not sure how to use it.  https://gist.github.com/yangchenyun/a1c123935d82f5e25d57

Comment: @jeramytownsley the github script works using nodejs as per this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1065010/589351)